# React Router v3 - IndexRoute not working in Google Cache

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-search, react-router-dom, react-dom

In React Router v3, `IndexRoute` not working in Google Cache (cache:www.mywebsite.com). It is showing Layout and NotFound component (instead of Layout and Home component). Please find below my sample router configuration.

```
<Route path='/' component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path='/users'>
        <Route path=':category/:id' component={User} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' exact={true} component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Do you have a service worker enabled? if so disable it.

Comment: No service worker used in code. Created project with Webpack 3

Comment: silly question.. does the component load by itself without routes?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `path` of the `Route` that is rendering your `Layout` and create a separate `Route` for a `path` of `/` as child to that.

**Example**

```
<Route component={Layout}>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/users" component={Users}>
    <Route path="user/:id" component={User} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

Comment: I think the "exact" prop is not needed here. This prop is available only in r-r v4. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @loelsonk Thanks. Updated the example as well.

Comment: Still not working. I just updated the exact code in the question. Can you check again and let me know why the code is not working only in Google Cache?

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh That's very frustrating. I don't know what it could be if the above doesn't fix it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove '/' from line one and also make sure you are using browserHistory:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Layout} >
  .
  .
  .
  </Route>
  </Router>
```

Comment: sorry for posting wrong code. updated code in question. please check it

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because it's trying to express // as a path to navigate to.

should be something like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        ...
    </Route>
    <Route component={Settings}>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        <Route path="settings" component={Settings} />
        ...
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this solution. Index route is working in this case.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import Greetings from './components/Greetings';
import SignupPage from './components/signup/SignupPage';
import LoginPage from './components/login/LoginPage';
import NewEventPage from './components/events/NewEventPage';

import requireAuth from './utils/requireAuth';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Greetings} />
    <Route path="signup" component={SignupPage} />
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="new-event" component={requireAuth(NewEventPage)} />
  </Route>
)
```

You can use these exported routes in your index file like this.

```
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```